# Select group from a List<T> matching a condition that cannot be directly specified on a property

Tags: c#, linq

I have following class specifying a data record

```
class DataRecord
{
    public double MeasuredValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime MeasurementDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select the records that were taken in a range of one hour (the date doesn't matter), where the count of the records taken is maximal.

Example:

1. MeasurementDate: 2019/01/31 11:50
2. MeasurementDate: 2019/02/02 17:21
3. MeasurementDate: 2019/03/01 17:59
4. MeasurementDate: 2019/03/12 10:54
5. MeasurementDate: 2019/05/28 11:15

Expected output: **1, 4, 5** (because within the span 10:50 - 11:50 3 measurements were made)

The code I came up with is

```
List<DataRecord> records = new List<DataRecord>();
var maxRecordsInAnHour = records.GroupBy(x => x.MeasurementDate.Hour)
                                .Aggregate((g1, g2) => { return g2.Count() > g1.Count() ? g2 : g1; });
```

This code returns either **2 and 3** or **1 and 5** (depending on the order) as I group by the `Hour` property and just records with the same value in `Hour` are grouped.

How can I adjust my code to get the expected output?

Comment: what if you just say `GroupBy(x => x.MeasurementDate)` since that's a `DateTime`

Comment: 10.50 how you want to define that lower limit? because from what I see your code is using XX:00 as lower limit and XX:59 as the upper limit, but your case has 10:50 as a lower limit

Comment: @Rahul Then I have a group for every unique date, which doesn't solve the problem. I think it is hard for me to find the right words to describe my problem properly.

Comment: @Mihir Dave The lower limit is not fix. I just chose something for the example. It could also be 10:51-11:51. The requirement is just the span of one hour, not a specific timeframe.

Comment: What do you want  to happen if there are the same maximum number of measurements in two 1-hour periods. For example, adding a measurement taken at 17:00 to your sample data.

Comment: And how much data will you be handling.?

Comment: @Sweeper Just return one of them. Which one doesn't matter.

Comment: @MihirDave Currently there are about 10000 records in that list.

Comment: @ErikT. I have something in mind but that'll have O(n^2) complexity if that's okay for you let me know I'll cook some example for you.

Comment: @MihirDave Still better than O(n!). So if you have something in mind I'd be glad if you share it with me.

Comment: Why do you need to do grouping at all, why not just a `Where`?

Comment: @DavidG If it is possible with a `Where` clause I'll also take that, but I couldn't figure out a proper `Where` statement, so I came up with that grouping approach.

Comment: So if I am understood correctly you must order all records by hour with minutes and then you must iterate that collection to find how many records is there for item + 60 min? For eaxample if the collection after ordering have records T1, T2, T3 you must check how many records excist for T1 + 60min, than T2 + 60min. Am I right?

Comment: @AzzyElvul Your description sounds correct. I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will propose 2 solutions for your problem, depend on the length of your list one will be better.

Initialize :

```
var myList = new List<DataRecord>
{
    new DataRecord
    {
        MeasurementDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 11, 50, 0)
    },
    new DataRecord
    {
        MeasurementDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 17, 21, 0)
    },
    new DataRecord
    {
        MeasurementDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 17, 59, 0)
    },
    new DataRecord
    {
        MeasurementDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 10, 54, 0)
    },
    new DataRecord
    {
        MeasurementDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 11, 54, 0)
    },
};

List<DataRecord> result = new List<DataRecord>();
```

Solution 1 :

```
var minimumMinutes = myList.Min(x => x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute);
var maximumMinutes = myList.Max(x => x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute);

for (int minutes = minimumMinutes; minutes < maximumMinutes; minutes++)
{
    var list = myList.Where(x =>
        x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute <= minutes + 60 &&
        x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute >= minutes);

    if (result.Count < list.Count())
    {
        result = list.ToList();
    }
}
```

Solution 2 :

```
foreach (var dataRecord in myList)
{
    var minutes = dataRecord.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + dataRecord.MeasurementDate.Minute;
    var before = myList.Where(x =>
        x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute >= minutes - 60 &&
        x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute <= minutes).ToList();
    var after = myList.Where(x =>
        x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute <= minutes + 60 &&
        x.MeasurementDate.Hour * 60 + x.MeasurementDate.Minute >= minutes).ToList();

    if (before.Count > result.Count ||
        after.Count > result.Count)
    {
        result = before.Count > after.Count ? before.ToList() : after.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I came up with a solution myself (Thanks to @AzzyElvul) I now have 4 different approaches. For 10000+ records your first solution has the best performance, so I'll use that.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments this code is not performance efficient, but this will do the trick.

```
// DummyData
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>
{
    DateTime.Parse("2019/01/31 11:50"),
    DateTime.Parse("2019/02/02 17:21"),
    DateTime.Parse("2019/03/01 17:59"),
    DateTime.Parse("2019/03/12 10:54"),
    DateTime.Parse("2019/05/28 11:15"),
};

// Storage for final Output
List<DateTime> finalOp = new List<DateTime>();

// Main logic goes here
// foreach Hour in list we will compare that with every other Hour in list
// and it is in 1 hour range we will add it to list
foreach (DateTime dateTime in dates)
{
    List<DateTime> temp = new List<DateTime>();
    foreach (DateTime innerDateTime in dates)
    {
        // find the difference between two hours
        var timeSpan = dateTime.TimeOfDay - innerDateTime.TimeOfDay;

        // add it to same list if we have +/- 1 Hour difference
        if (timeSpan.TotalHours <= 1 && timeSpan.TotalHours >= -1)
        {
            temp.Add(innerDateTime);
        }

    }

    // once we have final group for date we will check if this has maximum number of common dates around
    // if so replace it with previous choice
    if (finalOp.Count < temp.Count)
    {
        finalOp = temp;
    }
}

// print the results
foreach (var data in finalOp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.ToShortTimeString());
}
```

Comment: I tested 4 different solutions including yours, the two approaches by 'GuilhemPrev' and the one I came up with myself after 'AzzyElvul' commented on my question. Your solution was the fastest for up to ~1500 records, but as I have around 10000 records, solution 1 by 'GuilhemPrev' made the race. Anyway great answer with good comments.

Answer (score 0):

For the 10,000 items of `myList` collection this solution can be fast:

```
private static List<DataRecord> Get(List<DataRecord> myList)
    {
        var ordered = myList.OrderBy(x => x.MeasurementDate.TimeOfDay).ToList();
        int i = 0;
        int count = myList.Count();
        var temp =
            (from s in ordered
            let index = ++i
            let next = ordered.ElementAtOrDefault(index != count ? index : 0)
            select new
            {
                Cur = s.MeasurementDate,
                Diff = index != count
                    ? (next.MeasurementDate.TimeOfDay - s.MeasurementDate.TimeOfDay).TotalMinutes
                    : 24 * 60 - (ordered.ElementAtOrDefault(count - 1).MeasurementDate.TimeOfDay - ordered.ElementAtOrDefault(0).MeasurementDate.TimeOfDay).TotalMinutes
            }).ToList();

        Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        count = 0;
        double minutes = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < temp.Count(); index++)
        {
            for (int j = index; j < temp.Count(); j++)
            {
                minutes += temp[j].Diff;
                if (minutes > 60)
                {
                    dict.Add(index, count);
                    count = 0;
                    minutes = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        var max = dict.First(d => d.Value == dict.Values.Max());
        var finalResult = ordered.Skip(max.Key).Take(max.Value + 1).ToList();
        return finalResult;
    }
```

Please note it returns ordered results.